# Ruby errors unexpected line and unexpected keyword end

Tags: ruby, compiler-errors

I have a ruby code that supposes to read a paragraph and find the total number of characters, words, and sentences then find the ARI (Automated Readability Index) and decide which grade level.
I have the code here but when running it I'm getting these two errors, this is my first time using ruby so I'm not so familiar with its error.

here's the code

```
    def calcARI(paragraph)

      file = File.open(paragraph,"r")

      if file

        file_data = file.read

        file.close

        charCount=0

        wordCount=0

        sentenceCount=0

        ARIvalue==0

        gradeLevel=""

        file.each_line { |line|

            charCount+=line.size

            for i in 1..line.length

                if(line[i]=='.')

                    sentenceCount+=1

                end

                if(line[i]==' ')

                    {

                        wordCount+=1

                    }

                end

            end

            

        }

        ARIvalue==4.71*(charCount/wordCount)+0.5*(wordCount/sentenceCount)-21.43

        case ARIvalue

        when 1

            gradeLevel="5-6 Kindergarten"

        when 2

            gradeLevel="6-7 First/Second Grade"

        when 3

            gradeLevel="7-9 Third Grade"

        when 4

            gradeLevel="9-10 Fourth Grade"

        when 5

            gradeLevel="10-11Fifth Grade"

        when 6

            gradeLevel="11-12 Sixth Grade"

        when 7

            gradeLevel="12-13 Seventh Grade"

        when 8

            gradeLevel= "13-14 Eighth Grade"

        when 9

            gradeLevel= "14-15 Ninth Grade"

        when 10

            gradeLevel= "15-16 Tenth Grade"

        when 11

            gradeLevel= "16-17 Eleventh Grade"

        when 12

            gradeLevel= "17-18 Twelth Grade"

        when 13

            gradeLevel= "18-24 College student"

        when 14

            gradeLevel="24+ Professor"

        end        

        puts "Total # of Charecter: #{charCount}"

        puts "Total # of words: #{wordCount}"

        puts "Total # of sentences: #{sentenceCount}"

        puts "Total # of Automated Readability Index: #{ARIvalue}"

        puts "Grade Level: '#{gradeLevel}''"

    else

        puts "Unable to open file!"

    end

  end
```

and here are the errors

```
    main.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
...                   wordCount+=1
...                               ^
main.rb:128: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'
```

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove curly braces around `wordCount+=1`